# change scrollbar design

Tags: css, scrollbar, browser-scrollbars

anyone know how to re-design scrollbar slider for  IE ??not just a color but perform too..

Comment: what do mean by "not just a color but perform too.."??

Answer (score 6):

Googling will lead you to a variety of articles on this, including [*"10 jQuery Custom Scrollbar Plugins"*](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/).

In general, a redesign requires JavaScript to control the scrolling of an overflowed container.

Comment: He's right. You can't change the behavior of the browser's scrollbar. You're better off creating your own.

Comment: Note that while I was correct in my statement "in general", there are [webkit-specific extensions](http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) for custom styling (beyond colors).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be disabling the browser scroll bar and using a javascript solution instead. This, of course, would effect all browsers instead of just IE.

If you want to go that route, I highly recommend jScrollPane.
http://www.kelvinluck.com/projects/jscrollpane-custom-cross-browser-scrollbars/

After installing just add this to your css:
html, body {overflow: hidden;}

jScrollPAne is great because you can style it easily with CSS or custom images. You can also easily adjust the scrolling speed and other behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

While the extensions mentioned here are useful most of the time , I find that they are not on parity with native scrollbars.

For example a container with dynamic content or on resize will not trigger scrollbar resize which I find is huge limitation.([HTML5 Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) will probably make this easier in the future.)

For now I prefer [scrollbar styling](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) ,which has all the native functionality.
The downside is that is supported only by Webkit - Chrome and Safari browsers.

Still I consider that is a good trade-of... lately I notice Google is using the same technique for their apps (Gmail, G+, Reader, etc.)